# SharePoint 2013 REST upload from App works on image, fails on video

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Has anyone tried to upload a video via REST to SharePoint 2013 from a SharePoint hosted app?

Below are my two POSTs.  The first one, an image, works fine.  The second one **does** add my video but it throws a 404 (Not Found).  Subsequent executions do not overwrite but instead create new video files with some random letters afterwards.  The subsequent executions also pop the 404.

I should also point out the the overwrite flag is obviously being ignored because it always creates a new file.  Further when I tried to use the "manipulated" video URL that you see in a library after uploading it blows with a server error.

My suspicion is that it's because of the way SP2013 handles videos by creating items that don't retain their extension like an image does.  Anyone know for sure?

Or know if there's some sort of RESPONSE that is sent back that would cause the 404?

```
http://app2-6040b7dbcd33cc.sp13apps-qa.PATH/sites/XDevT/CustomNewsFeedEntry/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?@TargetSite=%27http://teamsites13-qa.PATH/sites/XDevT%27&@TargetLibrary=%27NewsFeedVideos%27&@TargetFileName=%27cg-overlay-img.jpg%27
http://app2-6040b7dbcd33cc.sp13apps-qa.PATH/sites/XDevT/CustomNewsFeedEntry/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@TargetSite)/web/lists/getByTitle(@TargetLibrary)/RootFolder/Files/add(url=@TargetFileName,overwrite='true')?@TargetSite=%27http://teamsites13-qa.PATH/sites/XDevT%27&@TargetLibrary=%27NewsFeedVideos%27&@TargetFileName=%27WMV_Movie.wmv%27
```